# Are "xxx/sec" performance counters in sys.dm_os_performance_counters actually rates or just counters?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to track SQL Server metrics using Prometheus by querying the system dynamic management views. I am looking into the Buffer Manager: Page reads/sec counter in `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`, which I understand to be a rate at which reads are happening, aggregated over an [unspecified] amount of time, based on the description in the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-buffer-manager-object?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Indicates the number of physical database page reads that are issued per second. ...

However, I have tracked the query for 8 databases (with differing SQL Server versions: 2012, 2017, 2019) over 12 hours, and the counter value for all of them seems pretty high (16K+ for a development database with no traffic, 700K+ for a production database with very little traffic).
Also, the values are not changing, or rather, are not changing very much (+/-200 page reads) and very infrecquently (once for each database over a 12 hour period).

This leads me to believe that this counter may actually not be a rate but a total count over time that must be converted into a rate by aggregating the values and comparing with the previous value. If I select the metric from Performance Monitor, it shows the rate as 0, which seems to confirm my suspicion. Is this correct? And if so, is this the case for all of the `/sec` counters?

For reference, this is the query I'm using to retrieve the counter.

```sql
select cntr_value from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where object_name = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager'
and counter_name = 'Page reads/sec';
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to DBA.SE. You might have noticed that your question was closed as a duplicate of a previous Q & A with an accepted answer. Did you read the answer? The explanation for the `cntr_value`  column has the following explanation: _For per-second counters, this value is cumulative. The rate value must be calculated by sampling the value at discrete time intervals. The difference between any two successive sample values is equal to the rate for the time interval used._ So yes, the values for `cntr_value` columns is cumulative and has to be aggregated. This question will remain closed.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, thank you. I tried searching for an answer before posting but couldn't find the right search terms. Should I edit this question at all?

Comment: Your question has a documented answer in a duplicate question and as such doesn't require an edit. An edit (change) would require a reopen and that would be the opposite of what the community wanted to achieve. If you search the SQL Server Docs for [sys.dm_os_performance_counters (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) then you should find the relevant information for future cases. The same is mostly true for any system management view. And what nbk wrote...

Comment: only when the posted link hasn't an answer for you